Unlocked package without DEV HUB
I wanted to create an unlocked package to deploy in Sandbox and later in production. I don't have access to DEV HUB for the below command to run
sf package create --name MyManagedPackage --description "Your Package Descripton" --package-type Managed --path force-app --target-dev-hub devhub@example.com

How could I do it? I have access to Sandbox.
Is there a way to create an Unlocked package on this scenario?

You can create a developer org and use that as a dev hub. It has very few scratch orgs permitted per day, but it is possible. Alternatively, if your business has a production org, that can and should be used as a dev hub, with increased limits and no fear that your dev hub might get decommissioned.

If your issue is that you don't have access to production for some reason, then you might want to check with your team about creating users with that specific Developer License. Then you will have limited access to the Dev Hub org and be able to use the package commands.

The Developer license is designed for users whose role is to build customizations or applications. This license provides access to development tools and environments. It comes with one Developer sandbox, one scratch org, and access to the Dev Hub. In the production org, this license restricts access to standard and custom objects. For example, users can’t access the Account object within the Sales app. And because of the restriction to custom objects, users can’t be assigned access to custom apps or AppExchange apps.


You cannot create an unlocked package without a Dev Hub - that org is used to track your scratch orgs and packages.  If you do not have access to a production org, you can use a free Developer Edition org as your Dev Hub, as Developer Edition orgs are hosted in Production pods.  You will be limited to 3 active scratch orgs (and only 6 created per day), but it can certainly be done.
